# cx_Freeze python single file?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I've been using cx_Freeze for a while now and there is one thing I've really wanted to do: put ALL files into ONE executable that I can distribute. It's not really user-friendly to send around a folder filled with 30 files, all in the same directory. How can I accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: PyInstaller does this. I'd like to know how to do it with cx_freeze as well.

Comment: I'd never heard of PyInstaller, and it looks awesome! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't this what `bbfreeze` does?

Tutorial here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/19/a-bbfreeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

It's actually not that hard to roll your own with Python zipimport http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html

You may prefer to use something like UPX which is a more general solution, not Python only. http://upx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Could you maybe put a little more effort into this answer?  No summary of how to do it, not even a link to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze

Comment: Unfortunately `bbfreeze` does not support Python3.

Comment: Note that as of 2014 bbfreeze is no longer maintained.  https://github.com/schmir/bbfreeze

Answer (score 18):

It is not supported in cx_freeze. There was discussion about it on mailing list. As I recall, the author stated that others (PyInstaller, Py2Exe) use some dirty hacks to achieve that. Some anti-virus programs can consider that behavior as a virus also.

I used PyInstaller for some time, but went back to cx_freeze because of Python 2.7 support. I pack everything using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), so it is easy to distribute. Depends if you use Windows or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'bdist_msi' instead of 'build'. This will create a dist folder in the directory with a **single setup application**.

http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

Comment: This creates an installer but not a single executable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables)

> cx_Freeze does not support building a single file exe, where all of the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable file.

The documentation gives some options to obtain a single file.

A further option under Windows is to use the `bdist_msi` command to create a single Microsoft Installer file (`.msi`) for your application, as mentioned by @QuaziRabbi. This command has few `cx_Freeze`-specific options documented [here](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#bdist-msi) to customize the installer. This command overloads the [`bdist_msi`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.bdist_msi) command of the `distutils` package which itself brings some more options to customize the installer. The available options are not documented, one need to look at the source code of the `distutils` package. Interesting examples are [Use cx-freeze to create an msi that adds a shortcut to the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15734703/8516269) and [cx_freeze bdist_msi: create registry entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51656310/8516269)

Another option is to use another tool to create a more customizable single-file installer for the frozen application after the `cx_Freeze` build step. The script-based tool [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) allows one to create a very customizable installer and the use of a script means that this step can be completely automatized. @Fenisko's answers mentions another tool, and there are many more.