# Why my freezed app is detected as possible virus?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have packed my python application using the cx_freeze tool, this is my setup.py script:

```
import sys, os,imp
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"],"include_files":["ui\images","imageformats","qt.conf","icon.ico"] }


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "MonPy-Qt",
        version = "1.5",
        description = "Conversor de Divisas",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base,icon="icon.ico")],
        icon="icon.ico")
```

But when I try to run the generated .exe, avast detects as possible virus:

[image: Trollvast]

Someone have any idea to avoid this? thanks :)

**Edit:**

Translated message:

> You are opening an application that may be potentially insecure. We
>   recomend open this application on the virtual environment Sandbox in
>   order to avoid any risk to the computer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5497896/471800 might have clues. probably need to know more about your program.

Comment: It's possible someone used `cx_Freeze` to make a virus, and they blacklisted anything that looks similar. Can you translate the message?

Comment: I've used `Py2Exe` a number of times and never had this type of problem. Things might have changed since then.... I was using `Py2Exe` early last year.

Comment: I just tried with py2exe and still having the same alert with the *.exe

Comment: It's interesting that it only says it's potentially insecure. Maybe it detects that it's going to run Python code, and decides that that's risky. Does running it in the sandbox work?

Comment: Yep, works perfectly on sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No Solution:**

A recent update on Avast Antivirus specifies the reason to alert saying "Reputation: low".

Thanks to all :)